# MySQL - Is there a way to change the ENCLOSED IN character for UPDATES?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am using EXCEL to create a group of UPDATE statement. A good number of rows have columns that contain single quote characters as part of the field value.  Is there a way I can tell MySQL to use a different ENCLOSURE character other than " or ' ?

It would be great to be able to change the character from the standard to a specific.
EXAMPLE -

```
UPDATE table SET length=~value~, width=~value~, etc.
```

Where ~ would be used in place of  " or  '   .

Schema for the Old Table -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pudoitems` (
  `PUDOItem_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PUDO_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDO_tab_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_make` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_model` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_equiptype` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_serial` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_weight` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_height` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_width` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_length` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_Notes` text,
  `loads_load_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PUDOItem_id`,`loads_load_id`),
  KEY `PUDOItem_make_idx` (`PUDOItem_make`),
  KEY `PUDOItem_model_idx` (`PUDOItem_model`),
  KEY `PUDOItem_makemodel_idx` (`PUDOItem_make`,`PUDOItem_model`),
  KEY `fk_PUDO_id` (`PUDO_id`),
  KEY `fk_pudoitems_loads1` (`loads_load_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2739 ;
```

Schema for the NEW Table -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pudoitems_cat` (
  `PUDOItem_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PUDO_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDO_tab_id_01` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_make_01` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_model_01` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_equiptype_01` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_serial_01` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_weight_01` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_height_01` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_width_01` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_length_01` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_Notes_01` text,
  `PUDO_tab_id_02` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_make_02` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_model_02` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_equiptype_02` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_serial_02` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_weight_02` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_height_02` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_width_02` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_length_02` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_Notes_02` text,  
  `PUDO_tab_id_03` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_make_03` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_model_03` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_equiptype_03` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_serial_03` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_weight_03` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_height_03` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_width_03` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_length_03` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_Notes_03` text,
  `PUDO_tab_id_04` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_make_04` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_model_04` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_equiptype_04` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_serial_04` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_weight_04` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_height_04` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_width_04` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_length_04` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_Notes_04` text,
  `PUDO_tab_id_05` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_make_05` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_model_05` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_equiptype_05` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_serial_05` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_weight_05` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_height_05` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_width_05` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_length_05` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_Notes_05` text,
  `PUDO_tab_id_06` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_make_06` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_model_06` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_equiptype_06` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_serial_06` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_weight_06` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_height_06` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_width_06` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_length_06` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_Notes_06` text,
  `PUDO_tab_id_07` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_make_07` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_model_07` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_equiptype_07` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_serial_07` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_weight_07` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_height_07` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_width_07` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_length_07` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_Notes_07` text,  
  `PUDO_tab_id_08` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_make_08` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_model_08` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_equiptype_08` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_serial_08` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_weight_08` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_height_08` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_width_08` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_length_08` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_Notes_08` text,
  `PUDO_tab_id_09` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_make_09` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_model_09` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_equiptype_09` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_serial_09` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_weight_09` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_height_09` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_width_09` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_length_09` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_Notes_09` text,
  `PUDO_tab_id_10` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_make_10` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_model_10` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_equiptype_10` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_serial_10` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_weight_10` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_height_10` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_width_10` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_length_10` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PUDOItem_Notes_10` text,
  `loads_load_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PUDOItem_id`,`loads_load_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF16 AUTO_INCREMENT=2900 ;
```

The PUDO_tab_id identifies which PUDOItem_[field]_[tag_id #] for a given PUDO_id.

Here is a sample UPDATE -

```
UPDATE PUDOItems_cat SET PUDO_tab_id_01=1 ,PUDOItem_make_01=", E2," ,PUDOItem_model_01=TR3520 / TWR3520  ,PUDOItem_equiptype_01=TUGGERS ,PUDOItem_serial_01=SEE ATTACHED ,PUDOItem_weight_01=12000 ,PUDOItem_height_01=6" ,PUDOItem_width_01=8 ,PUDOItem_length_01=40 ,PUDOItem_Notes_01= WHERE PUDOItem_id =1;
UPDATE PUDOItems_cat SET PUDO_tab_id_02=2 ,PUDOItem_make_02='LOADING TIMES:' ,PUDOItem_model_02='730A - 300PM '  ,PUDOItem_equiptype_02='*CALL 1 HR PRIOR TO ' ,PUDOItem_serial_02='ARRIVAL*' ,PUDOItem_weight_02=0 ,PUDOItem_height_02='' ,PUDOItem_width_02='' ,PUDOItem_length_02='' ,PUDOItem_Notes_02='' WHERE PUDOItem_id =1;
UPDATE PUDOItems_cat SET PUDO_tab_id_01=1 ,PUDOItem_make_01=' CAT' ,PUDOItem_model_01='NDC100'  ,PUDOItem_equiptype_01='FORKLIFT' ,PUDOItem_serial_01='2HL11637' ,PUDOItem_weight_01=0 ,PUDOItem_height_01='' ,PUDOItem_width_01='' ,PUDOItem_length_01='' ,PUDOItem_Notes_01='' WHERE PUDOItem_id =2;
UPDATE PUDOItems_cat SET PUDO_tab_id_02=2 ,PUDOItem_make_02='CAT' ,PUDOItem_model_02='NDC100'  ,PUDOItem_equiptype_02='FORKLIFT' ,PUDOItem_serial_02='2HL11674' ,PUDOItem_weight_02=0 ,PUDOItem_height_02='' ,PUDOItem_width_02='' ,PUDOItem_length_02='' ,PUDOItem_Notes_02='' WHERE PUDOItem_id =2;
UPDATE PUDOItems_cat SET PUDO_tab_id_03=3 ,PUDOItem_make_03=' 2 BATTERIES' ,PUDOItem_model_03='1 CHARGER PER'  ,PUDOItem_equiptype_03='MACHINE' ,PUDOItem_serial_03='' ,PUDOItem_weight_03=45000 ,PUDOItem_height_03='8' ,PUDOItem_width_03='8' ,PUDOItem_length_03='48' ,PUDOItem_Notes_03='' WHERE PUDOItem_id =2;
UPDATE PUDOItems_cat SET PUDO_tab_id_01=1 ,PUDOItem_make_01='MIDLAND' ,PUDOItem_model_01=''  ,PUDOItem_equiptype_01='DIRT BUCKET' ,PUDOItem_serial_01='' ,PUDOItem_weight_01=4000 ,PUDOItem_height_01='' ,PUDOItem_width_01='8' ,PUDOItem_length_01='18' ,PUDOItem_Notes_01='' WHERE PUDOItem_id =16;
```

The first 2 UPDATES build out PUDO_id = 1, while the next 3 UPDATES build out PUDO_id = 2, and the last UPDATE builds out PUDO_id = 16.

Comment: You need to put 3 quotes for each single quote to escape them. Find and replace should do it, or a cheeky column that does it for you before you concatenate.

Comment: I understand the "cheeky column" implementation. How will MySQL handle the single-quote? Ooo, I think I just answered the question. Use double-quotes on all fields requiring them and implement the "cheeky" for fields with single-quotes. -Cheers!

Comment: What if I just REPLACE all single-quotes in the field with ~ , then insert, update, and finally convert the tilda back to single-quote.

Comment: Yes you could do that, I personally would go for the pipe (|) as tilde could be used in a sentence...

Comment: I will use the pipe ( | ) approach.

Answer (score 1):

I believe such a setting would violate the ANSI standard.

Whenever I need to do stuff like this, I'll use weird characters in Excel, and then I use Notepad or Ultraedit to do a global replace...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution, not a direct answer to your question

Instead of preparing `UPDATE statements` in Excel:

1. use it what it's best for - just prepare your data leaving alone the quotes that you have
2. export your update data to a file in a tab or comma delimited form
3. create a temporary staging table
4. load your data into the staging table using `LOAD DATA INFILE` as it is
5. issue `UPDATE` statement or statements that will update you factual table or tables.
6. `DROP` your temporary staging table

Comment: I understand and have done Steps 1 - 4. I am not clear on Step 5, because I do not understand how I set the values.  Am I able to use a SELECT to feed the values that need to be set?

Comment: Just do update with join. If you need help with that just post temp table and factual tables schema

Comment: I will post the schema. It will not be pretty, I am taking the data to 1st normal form.